# Memory allocation failure using new

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have allocated memory using operator new. The type of data to which memory needs to be allocated is 'uint8_t' and I am using 'uint32_t' type for the size . For example,

```
ptr = new uint8_t[size];
```

where ptr is of type uint8_t and size is of type uint32_t.

Now, we have got memory crash which points to this type of allocation in our code and the error message thrown was:

"_int_malloc: Assertion (unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb) failed."

One of our team member suggests that mismatch of ptr and size is the reason for the crash and I disagree with him.

Please explain if this could be the reason for the crash and if so, how ?

Also, Please explain what are the cases where we get the above error message.

Comment: @CoryKramer Why would you _not_ be allowed to do it? What if I needed 1024 char long text as an array? Mismatch between the type of the array size and the data type of what the array holds causing errors sounds ridiculous. - Unless I misunderstood the asker or the comment of yours.

Shivakumar - How large is size? Are you sure you free ptr once you dont use it?

Comment: @Rochet2 I think I misunderstood their question. I though `ptr` was of type `uint32_t*` but they are allocating a `new uint8_t[]`

Comment: @Rochet2 We will be writing data of size 1476 continously and yes we are freeing the ptr once we dont use it. This issue is not found everytime but so far 2 times out of 100 times we tested.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `size` doesn't really matter: whatever type it is, it's essentially being passed as a parameter to a function that takes `size_t`.

```
uint32_t size = 10;
uint8_t *ptr = new uint8_t[size];
```

This is perfectly valid code and there's no need for the type of `ptr` and `size` to be coordinated.

---

The error you're encountering at this line is indicating an internal error in the memory allocation library. It can appear to be caused by legal code when your program has elsewhere done something illegal that corrupts the state of the program.

You may be able to find the initial cause by using some other analysis tools such as valgrind, ubsan, or perhaps a static analyzer.